# How a javascript pubsub/observer sees the function of another object?

Tags: javascript, object, design-patterns, publish-subscribe, observer-pattern

I have this simple code, while trying to learn the basics of implementing the pubsub method in javascript.

`people` object emits a simple event and `events` object is the pubsub, takes the event and emits it to all that listen

Then `stats` that listens for that event, executes a function, with the data that came from the pubsub.

```js
var events = {
  events: {},
  on: function(eventName, fn) {
    this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
    this.events[eventName].push(fn);
  },
  emit: function(eventName, data) {
    if (this.events[eventName]) {
      this.events[eventName].forEach(function(fn) {
        console.log('events this ', this);
        fn(data)
      });
    }
  }
}

var stats = (function() {
  var counterstats = 0
  events.on('peoplechange', setPeople);

  function setPeople(a) {
    console.log('stats this ', this);
    counterstats++;
    console.log('stats people ', a)
  }
})();

var people = (function() {
  console.log('people this ', this);
  events.emit('peoplechange', 5);
})();
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
```

I am asking, how `events` knows and communicates with `setPeople` that is inside `stats`. `setPeople` is a method of an object, not exposed.

How `events` sees it? I thought I had to do `events.on('peoplechange', events.setPeople);` so `events` knows where this method belongs to.

I print the `this` of the function in the emit, and the `this` of the `setPeople` in the `stats` and they all point to Window.

I still cannot explain how `events` sees `setPeople` inside the `stats`, without specifying further.

Any explanation would be great. Apologies for asking basic things

Comment: "*setPeople is a method of an object, not exposed.*" 1. `setPeople` is a function and it;s not attached to any object. 2. How is it "not exposed" when it's directly passed into `events.on('peoplechange', setPeople);`?

Comment: In the `events.on(...., setPeople)`, the `setPeople` is a local function, visible in the scope. Reference to that function can be then stored in the `events['peoplechange']`.

Comment: And since the emitter calls functions directly (`fn(data)`), they got the default `this` binding.

Comment: `var stats =` and `var people =` don't make any sense, your IIFEs return `undefined`.

Comment: "*`setPeople` is a method of an object*" - no it isn't, it's a standalone function. (In fact, *every* function is, as JS has [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) and is not a class-based language that only knows methods).